# Scaling from local VM minikube/microk8s testing to testing on real cluster on AWS

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, microk8s

All -

I am a K8s newbie. I am trying to get a test a setup going with the following intention – I want to be able to have a setup configuration that I can use without much modification regardless of whether I use microk8s/minikube to run K8s or EKS on AWS. Is this possible?

Specifically, I want to setup a cluster with N components. For local testing each of these components may ask for small amount of resources for local VM testing (like 2GB disk, 1GB RAM, dns resolution locally etc.) while for the EKS testing these components will be requesting much larger resources (255GB disk, 8GB RAM, real load balancer instead of just dns resolution in EKS etc.)

Are there some resources to help me accomplish that? Any links to articles/books will help on this topic

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having?  In general (assuming your local-VM cluster is powerful enough) I'd expect almost any Kubernetes setup to work pretty much the same way.

Comment: This would depend on what exact resorces you want to setup. If we are talking about resources like for example `Ingress` there are differences in setup process between  minikube and AWS. Please take a look here: [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress Nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).